# Underscore and dash in column names after JSON import

Tags: openrefine

I've been using OpenRefine very successfully for a couple of years, working solely with CSV (and TSV) source files. Recently I had some tables from an sql database that I wanted to bring into `OpenRefine` so I exported them (from SQL) as JSON and then used `OpenRefine`'s JSON import feature. It works beautifully except that the column names all begin with `_ -` . For example, my JSON records start with

```
{"ID":"97247",
```

and `OpenRefine` made the first column name `_ - ID` instead of just `ID` (which I'd prefer - I know I can edit them later, but I have hundreds of fields). I can't see any settings in the parsing page that might help this. Does anyone know if there is a way to import without the extra characters (or if there's an explanation for the underscore dash)? I'm considering submitting a feature request but I thought I'd check to see what other users may know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/1017).

There has also been [a proposal to switch to a standard representation for JSON paths](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/2201).

Feel free to comment on either tickets to indicate which solution you would prefer.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was after.